# Regex syntax for replacing multiple strings: where have I gone wrong?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with the column 'purpose' that has a lot of string values that I want to standardize by finding a string and replacing it.

For instance, some very similar values are *car purchase, buying a second-hand car, buying my own car, cars, second-hand car purchase, car, to own a car, purchase of a car, to buy a car*

I used the following to make this change:

*#replace anything to do with buying a car with "Vehicle"*

```
credit_data['purpose'] = credit_data.purpose.str.replace(r'(^.*car.*$)','Vehicle')
```

and it worked great, all of those values were replaced with 'Vehicle'

I have a number of other similar strings in this column for other types, like education - *supplementary education, education, getting an education, to get a supplementary education, university education, etc.*

so, I looked up regex syntax and came up with the following:

*#replace anything to do with education with "Education"*

```
credit_data['purpose'] = credit_data.purpose.str.replace(r'(^.*education|university|educated.*$)','Education')
```

the results for this are similar to above - everything says education now - yay!

which brings me to my question - I've gone wrong somewhere in applying this to some of my other strings -  for instance, I used a similar method for real estate:

*#replace anything to do with real estate with real estate*

```
credit_data['purpose'] = credit_data.purpose.str.replace(r'(^.*real estate|housing|house|property.*$)','Real Estate')
```

and my results here are different - I started with values like *purchase my own house, building a house, purchase of a property, etc.* and all the method seems to have done was replace just the string i identified, instead of the entire string with just the replacement string.

so instead of having a bunch of entries that say "Real Estate" I have a bunch of entries that say *purchase my own Real Estate, building a Real Estate, purchase of a Real Estate, etc.*

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

edited to add requested series from the dataframe:

`Df = [purchase of the house, car purchase, supplementary education, to have a wedding, housing, transactions, education, having a wedding, purchase of the house for my family, buy real estate, buy commercial real estate, buy residential real estate, construction of own property, property, building a property, buying a second-hand car, buying my own car, transactions with commercial real estate, building a real estate, housing, transactions with my real estate, cars, to become educated, second-hand car purchase, getting an education, car, wedding ceremony, to get a supplementary education, purchase of my own house, real estate transactions, getting higher education, to own a car, purchase of a car, profile education, university education, buying property for renting out, to buy a car, housing renovation, going to university]`

Comment: can you provide a sample dataframe for us to see/test?  You can code format the contents of `df.to_dict()` for example

Comment: you may find https://regex101.com helpful if you haven't already seen it.  You can use it for fast feedback on regex match/replacement operations

Comment: Applying `replace(r'(^.car.$)','Vehicle')` to "buying a second-hand car" doesn't work because the regex explicitly looks for "car" as the 2nd, 3rd and 4th values of a 5 character string - that's what the "^." and ".$" do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the regular expression too restrictive and using the wrong character for alternation. You can use `\b` to match a word boundary, `|` to match multiple patterns and IGNORECASE to cover case issues. So for example

```
credit_data.purpose.str.replace(r'\b(real estate|housing|house|property)\b',
    'Real Estate', regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

If you want to replace the entire string, you can use dot-all (`.*`).

```
credit_data.purpose.str.replace(r'.*(real estate|housing|house|property).*',
    'Real Estate', regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! that seems to function better, but still leaves me with results like - *"purchase a real estate for my family" when i was hoping to drop the rest of the characters to end up with simply *"real estate"* i'll read more on regex101 but do you know if there is a way to drop the rest of the character string?

Comment: Oh, you want to replace the whole thing? Then you may need the end terminators after all. Let me add an example.